# Elegant way in Angular to enable submit if all child forms but the last are valid

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the simple Angular app I'm working on there is a parent form with various child forms that are created from an ng-repeat. I'd like a submit button to be tied to the parent form's $valid property OR some other simple way to enable the submit button when the form is what I consider to be valid. However, due to the user workflow a new child form is added after the fields of the last child form are completed. Thus, even a perfect form's last row is always empty & thus invalid (as there are required fields). Any suggestions on how to handle enable/disable of a submit button in this situation? I've created a fiddle that shows the issue. There is a submit button linked to the parent form's $valid, which does not show up unless the last form (row) is valid. Then there's a second submit button, whose enabled property I control by explicitly looking at all child forms and setting a scope variable to true or false based on my requirements. I think this solution is inelegant and there's got to be a better way.

https://jsfiddle.net/godinger/r5yx5z4b/

Here's the HTML form:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <pre>Parent Form Valid: {{parentForm.$valid}}</pre>
  <ng-form name="parentForm">
    <div ng-repeat="person in people">
      <ng-form name="childForm" novalidate>
        <input name="firstName"
        required
        ng-model="person.firstName"
        ng-init="person.form=childForm"/>
      <input name="lastName"
        required
        ng-model="person.lastName"
        ng-init="person.form=childForm"/>
        <span>Valid: {{childForm.$valid}}</span>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
    <button ng-submit ng-disabled="parentForm.$invalid">
      Submit
    </button>
    <button ng-submit ng-disabled="!enableSubmit">
      Workaround Submit
    </button>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

And here's the Angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.enableSubmit = false;

    $scope.people = [
        {firstName: 'John', lastName: "Adams"},
      {firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Hamilton'},
      {firstName: '', lastName:''}];

    $scope.$watch(updateSubmit);

    function updateSubmit(){
        if (!$scope.people){
        $scope.enableSubmit = false;
        return;
      }

        var numberOfPeople = $scope.people.length;
      for (var i=0; i<numberOfPeople-1; i++){
            var personForm = $scope.people[i].form;
        if (personForm.$invalid){
            $scope.enableSubmit = false;
          return;
        }
      }

      var lastPerson = $scope.people[numberOfPeople-1];
      var lastPersonForm = lastPerson.form;
      if (lastPersonForm.$valid){
        $scope.enableSubmit = true;
        return;
      }

      if (lastPerson.firstName || lastPerson.lastName){
                $scope.enableSubmit = false;
        return;         
      }else{
        $scope.enableSubmit = true;
        return;
      }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your implementation makes the most sense, but if want you want to do is provide "different html" based on the last element in `ng-repeat`, the simplest way is to use the `$last` element local variable. There are a number of ways to do this...but here is the simplest answer to your question:

```
 <ng-form ng-if="!$last" name="childForm" novalidate>
        <input name="firstName" placeholder="First name"
        ng-model="person.firstName"
        ng-init="person.form=childForm"/>
      <input name="lastName"
        required placeholder="First name"
        ng-model="person.lastName"
        ng-init="person.form=childForm"/>
        <span>Valid: {{childForm.$valid}}</span>
      </ng-form>
      <div ng-if="$last">
        Do Other Logic / Show other stuff (this could even be repeat all the form elements again, but remove all of the 'required' properties)
      </div>
```

Comment: Your idea to leverage $last helps a lot. I've implemented a function that ng-required calls that checks if $last is true and if all of the inputs are empty. https://jsfiddle.net/godinger/qpmma6oz/4/. Now the submit button can be tied to the form's validity, and there's no need to use a watch.